# delete on cascade, error FOREIGN KEY constraint failed, sqlite

Tags: android, foreign-keys, android-sqlite

When I delete a Chat row I want to delete all messages rows and all relations rows created with that `id_chat`. I don't have problems adding registers at this point but deleting relations and messages registers as they don't disappear automatically.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Chats (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, A1 DATE)");
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Messages (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FOREIGN KEY(id_user) REFERENCES Users(id_user), FOREIGN KEY(id_chat) REFERENCES Chats(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)");
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Relations (id_viaje INTEGER, id_chat INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (id_chat, id_viaje), FOREIGN KEY (id_chat) REFERENCES Chats(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (id_viaje) REFERENCES Viajes(_id))");
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Users (_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT, id_user TEXT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Viajes (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date DATE, activate BOOLEAN, id_user TEXT not null)");
     }
}
```

So as I read in stackoverflow I overrode the method `onOpen` in order to activate the foreign keys:

```
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db){
    super.onOpen(db);
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
}
```

edit:
And now the first register in Relations was added (1,17) the second one (3,17) gives me an error in the local db:

```
Error inserting id_viaje=3 id_chat=17 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Why this error? how to delete on cascade?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Table `Chats` does not have a column named `id_chat`

So this foreign key declaration in table `Relations` is not valid:

```
FOREIGN KEY (id_chat)  REFERENCES Chats(id_chat) ON DELETE CASCADE
                                        ^^^^^^^
```

---

The question is tagged with "mysql", but it appears you are actually using SQLite rather than MySQL. There are some differences between the two. For example, the `PRAGMA foreign keys` isn't valid in MySQL.

Comment: you're right, I edited it. Thanks. Still having some issues creating the registers in Relations, every Chat that I create it should create at least 2 registers in relations, I only can insert the first one.

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to remove id_viaje as a foreign key in my table Relations. Just:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Relations (id_viaje INTEGER, id_chat INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (id_chat, id_viaje), FOREIGN KEY (id_chat) REFERENCES Chats(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)");
```

The constraint exception is gone and deleting on cascade works.

Not sure why this happens, because both id_viaje an id_chat are foreign keys in my server and I don't have any issue when adding or deleting registers.